# SOAP request to create sales order shipment partially

Tags: magento, soap

I'm trying to create the sales order shipment partially in magento with the following request [1]. I get "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules". Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[1]

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
         <sessionId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
         <orderIncrementId>200006672</orderIncrementId>
         <itemsQty><orderItemIdQty><order_item_id>AG0102019</order_item_id><qty>1.0</qty></orderItemIdQty></itemsQty>
         <comment>Testing</comment>
         <email>1</email>
      </urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out the root cause of this issue. The order_item_id is an integer type element and the passed value is string. So that the 'Violation of encoding rules' issue comes.

The request should be like this,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
             <sessionId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
             <orderIncrementId>200006672</orderIncrementId>
             <itemsQty>
                    <urn:orderItemIdQty>
                        <order_item_id>13066</order_item_id>
                        <qty>1.0</qty>
                    </urn:orderItemIdQty>
                </itemsQty>
          </urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```